I‘m using CVXPY, how to write these function with disciplined convex programming rule？ $\log_2(2^x-1)$
How to write these function with disciplined convex programming rule? $\log_2(2^x-1)$.
$2^x$ here is not large enough to igore -1.
I've tried log_sum_exp(x*log(2)), but I can not deal with the -1 term

That always lies between $x - 1$ and $x$ for $x \ge 1$. Do you really need an exact constraint?
